# JK FlipFlop code debug

Tags: vhdl

Following is the code for JK FlipFlop:-

```
entity jkasync is
Port ( j : in std_logic;
       k : in std_logic;
       r : in std_logic;
       clk : in std_logic;
       q : inout std_logic);
 end jkasync;

architecture Behavioral of jkasync is
signal s: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
s <= j&k;
begin

  process (j,k,r,clk)
  begin

        if (r='1') then
        q<='0';
        elsif (falling_edge(clk)) then
        case    s is
        when "00" =>q<=q;
        when "01" =>q<='0';
        when "10" =>q<='1';
        when "11" =>q<= not q;
        when others =>q<='0';
        end case;
        end if;
    end process;


  end Behavioral;
```

And I am getting the following error:-

**Line 21. parse error, unexpected IDENTIFIER**

where line 21 is `s<=j&k;`
So please help me correct the syntax of this code and please tell me what is wrong here.
Thank You.

Comment: You can't make any signal assignment before the begin of architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

A new signal is initialized in the architecture body but the value is defined inside the process body.

SO move the line 21 inside process.

Correct Code:-

```
   architecture Behavioral of jkasync is
  signal s: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

  begin
  s <= j&k;
  process (j,k,r,clk)
  begin

        if (r='1') then
        q<='0';
        elsif (falling_edge(clk)) then
        case    s is
        when "00" =>q<=q;
        when "01" =>q<='0';
        when "10" =>q<='1';
        when "11" =>q<= not q;
        when others =>q<='0';
        end case;
        end if;
    end process;


        end Behavioral;
```